# Deploying to live server via link on email notification

Tags: jenkins

I've been reading a few articles and watching a few videos on Jenkins.  I'm wondering how easy it would be once the master branch has been deployed to a staging server to automatically send an email to the client notifying them of the url to the staging server and also giving them a link to "deploy live".  This way the client can see the changes, make sure they're happy with it then deploy it themselves without having to email anyone requesting it to go live.

Anyone got any idea how easy this would be to do with Jenkins?  There may be a plugin that does this but so far I've not come across anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw a talk where a guy does this to notify QA of a new build to test, as well as notify when a build is ready to be published to production.

Basically the last automated job (deploy to staging job) has a post build step to send an email to some address. The body of the email contains a link back to the REST API for the "deploy to production" job, triggering a build.

Email recipient tests things, and if satisfied, clicks the link and Jenkins runs the production job. Obviously this requires that the recipient has some kind of access to (at the very least, the REST API of) the Jenkins instance. That being said, there's no reason you couldn't set up your own system to take limited external requests and forward them to your Jenkins API.

The video link (including time reference of the relevant part) is: https://youtu.be/3HI7mv_791k?t=3169

If you've been watching a few videos you might have already come across it, but it's quite long so you might not have watched it all.